# showing a white screen after every new version deployment react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, caching

I've deployed a react js application with digitalocean app platform and there's an express js file to make react js as a production application. when I deploy my application it loads smoothly. But when I deploy a new version browsers show only a white screen for the index page. But I can manually route to other pages like /about, /stlogin. Also, the console shows an error stating
**Unexpected token '<'**  **main.229b5112.chunk.js:1** . But after clearing the browser cache it loads without any problem. I tried giving a homepage to the package.json file but it didn't work.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(8080);
```

build folder and server.js are in same level.